# Django - Memcached issues

Tags: django, memcached

I have enabled memcached on a server that I manage. We have a few pages that show upwards of 1,000 records (this is necessary). With memcached, it loads almost instantly - which is great. However, sometimes that page should contain zero records although when we navigate to that page, it still shows all 1,000 records. Conversely, sometimes it should show 1,000 records but, since the page used to show zero records, the page loads from memory and, as a result, show zero records.

I'm just wondering how to deal with this. Basically, how to get the memcache system to know when the request is actually for a different set of data and not just load the cached page.

Here's my settings.py file (relevant lines):

```
  CACHES = {
      'default': {
          'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
          'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
      }
  }
```

and then further down in middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
 )
```

Any thoughts? Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just looking @ the dev version of Django Docs.

As per your [caching middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware)... those two middleware classes are the "lazy" way to cache - it caches every page for [CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#cache-middleware-seconds) seconds (if not set defaults to 600 seconds).

You can do [low-level caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) and have it determine in that view/method whether or not the data is changed and display it accordingly. Not sure how you determine that the data changes/should change, although I believe you'd want this type of caching as opposed to that caching middleware.

I only recently learned about how to cache with django and their [cache documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) helps quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess the main issue is trying to determine when the system should reload a page or simply show the cached version. I think, regardless of the method (lazy or per-view), I am missing this step. I, too, am new to Django caching so it's a fair amount of learning, as all things programming are.